# How to change date value based on no.o.days given

Tags: php

i have one datepicker in my form it get some default date from database.now i need to add one textbox asking no.of.days based on textbox value the previous datepicker value get changed.

Eg : in that datepicker column the date is 03-09-15.i give no.of.days as 10 it get chnaged to 13-09-15 how i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

When changing the date from the code, you'd use a `setDate` method:

**HTML :**

```
<div id="date"></div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker();

    //handle date here. It is passed as var. So u can make changes here

   var date = '01/09/2014';

   $("#date").datepicker('setDate', date);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/abhighosh18/p9L01zzd/1/)

Comment: Did you see the fiddle ?

Comment: function KeyHandler() {
        var result = document.getElementById('result');
        result.innerHTML=document.getElementById('day').value;
           }

Comment: i am using this script to get the textbox value.now i need this value in a php variable

Comment: i didnt need like that when i give no.of.days based on that the value in date field get changed automaticlly

Comment: That will happen u have to give that on the click function which i have displayed in the fiddle! Does ur problem resolve ?

Comment: <input type="text" id="dt1">
<input type="text" id="dt2">
    <input type="text" id="dt3">

Comment: @KIDDO : do you want the date to be displayed by default ?  and then when you give number of days, that many days should increase automatically right ?

Comment: date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 10); instead of this 10 i need to give dt3 get value get value only get addded how i achieve

Comment: so u want 3 date pickers ??

Comment: no that dt3 value is to get no.of.days based on that dt2 get changed

Comment: see this jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/PPSh3/3/ in that there is defaultly one get added. but instead of that one as default i need what dt3 textbox value  contain

Comment: Okkay! So your problem is resolved right ? In the fiddle u have shown ?

Comment: instead of giving  10 as default directly, how i get it from user and add the value given by user